# Adding multiple span from javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div on which i can type text using span and textarea(which is hidden). I am calling this div onclick function. What i want is on each click i should see a div or span. i.e. multiple divs on the same page.
**CODE**:

```
<div class="EaDetail EaDetailText" style="left: 299px; top: 80px; font-size: 17px; width: 126px; height: 23px; position: absolute; display: block;">
<div class="EaDetailInset">
<span style="font-size: 17px;">
<br>
</span>
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="addTextBox()" value="Add">
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
function addTextBox()
{
$('.EaDetailInset').show();
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.EaDetail, .EaDetailDisabled {
border: 1px dashed transparent;
font-size: 12px;
overflow: visible;
position: absolute;
display:none;
}
.EaDetail {
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;

}

.EaDetailInset {
display: none;
max-height: 65px;
padding-bottom:5px;
border: 2px dashed #AAAAAA;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}


.EaDetailText textarea, .EaDetailText span {
font: 100%/1.1 arial,sans-serif;
position: absolute;
white-space: pre;
}
.EaDetailText textarea, .EaDetailText textarea[disabled] {
background: none repeat scroll 0 center transparent;
border: 0 none;
bottom: 6px;
box-shadow: none;
color: #000000;
display: block;
height: 200%;
left: 6px;
line-height: 1.1;
outline: 0 none;
padding: 0;
resize: none;
right: 6px;
top: 6px;
transition: none 0s ease 0s;
width: 200%;
}
```

Comment: I aint facing any error. I am able to get the div onclick but that is done only once when i click. I want to generate multiple divs onclick. That is when i click again another similar div should be generated with same functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="EaDetail EaDetailText" style="left: 299px; top: 80px; font-size: 17px; width: 126px; height: 23px; position: absolute; display: block;">
<div class="EaDetailInset">
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="addTextBox()" value="Add">

function addTextBox()
{
var newTextBoxdiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("class",'EaDetailInset');

    newTextBoxdiv.html('<span style="font-size: 17px;"><br></span><textarea></textarea></span>');

    newTextBoxdiv.insertAfter(".EaDetailInset");
  $(".EaDetailInset").show();
}
```

see if this works

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: $( '.EaDetailInset' ).draggable().resizable(); doesn't work for the div that i am calling from function but works for the one which i call manually. Why?

Comment: @shabbir.rang can you show your implementation??..preferably in jsfiddle

Comment: @shabbir.rang hmm..edit your code and show you implemented draggable function

Comment: Hey i am able to drag and resize. now the problem is that when i click button it adds div. perfect. Now when i call it again it adds two. And then again onclick it adds 4, then 8. I hope your understanding what i am trying to say?

Comment: @shabbir.rang unless you show code i cannot tell where the error is

Comment: Look i am referring to your code and saying this. on button click a div with class name (.EaDetailInset) is created which is placed after the already created (.EaDetailInset) right?  Now on each button click the divs are created below the already called dynamic divs. That is it shows earlier divs also and new ones also.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to *call* the javascript **function** correctly:
change

```
<input type="button" onclick="addTextBox" value="Add">
```

into

```
<input type="button" onclick="addTextBox()" value="Add">
```

Comment: Changed. Can you please be more specific to what i require?

Comment: it's not exactly clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to add multiple spans and divs, you will need to create those elements and append them a certain parent item. check http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple `textarea/span`, you need to create and append child elements to your `div`, what you are doing is just show/hide that will not replicate the elements.

```
var txt = document.createElement('textarea');
document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(txt);
```

Comment: I understand what you saying and really appreciate it. But what i exactly want to know is 'Can i call the same method twice'? So that i get the same span/textarea twice on clicking the button twice?